How to Code Adjacency Matrix
do you know how to code this in latex?


what did you try so far?

Welcome. // There were already similar questions here. Search for nicematrix .

with nicematrix, it's super easy

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{A}_H = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
    & v_6 & v_3 & v_4 & v_5 & v_1 & v_2 \\
v_6 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   \\
v_3 & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 1   \\
v_4 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   \\
v_5 & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   \\
v_1 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   \\
v_2 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0   \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}


Nice, but you're conditioning a new user on "wrong" behaviour: we'd like to see own attempts ;-)

@MS-SPO I cannot disagree. My bad. But the answer was so straighforward...

No problem ... happens to all of us every now and then ...

This is an interesting problem. Here I define a data structure for graphs, providing for printing the adjacency matrix, but we can imagine other uses.
The idea is to store the indices for the vertices in a sequence and the list of edges in another sequence.
The vertex list is mapped (twice) to check whether a given edge is in the edge list; in this case 1 is added to the body of the matrix, otherwise 0.
Using nicematrix allows to also fill the outer row and column.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definegraph}{mmm}
 {% #1 = graph name, #2 = vertex list, #3 = edge list
  \ryl_graph_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\adjacencymatrix}{m}
 {% #1 = graph name
  \ryl_graph_adjacency:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ryl_graph_define:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l__graph_vertex_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l__graph_vertex_#1_seq } { #2 }
  \seq_clear_new:c { l__graph_edge_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l__graph_edge_#1_seq } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ryl_graph_adjacency:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl
  \seq_map_inline:cn { l__graph_vertex_#1_seq }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl { & v\sb{##1} }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl { \\ }
  \seq_map_inline:cn { l__graph_vertex_#1_seq }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl { v\sb{##1} }
    \seq_map_inline:cn { l__graph_vertex_#1_seq }
     {
      \seq_if_in:cnTF { l__graph_edge_#1_seq } { ##1-####1 }
       {% the edge is in
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl { & 1 }
       }
       {
        \seq_if_in:cnTF { l__graph_edge_#1_seq } { ####1-##1 }
         {% the edge is in
          \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl { & 1 }
         }
         {
          \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl { & 0 }
         }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
  \tl_use:N \l__ryl_graph_adjacency_tl
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definegraph{A}{1,2,3}{1-2,1-3,2-3}
\definegraph{B}{6,3,4,5,1,2}{6-3,6-5,3-6,3-4,3-2,4-3,4-5,5-1,1-2}

\begin{document}


\[
\adjacencymatrix{A}
\]

\[
\mathbf{A}_{H}=\adjacencymatrix{B}
\]

\end{document}

In the second example, you can see that listing duplicate edges is irrelevant.


Very good code, as usual. Maybe \definegraph{B}{6,3,4,5,1,2}{6:3-5,3:6-4-2,4:3-5,5:1,1:2} would be a better API.

@projetmbc I don't think so: edges are charcterized by their two ends.

Using kbordermatrix package:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{A}_H = 
\kbordermatrix{
& v_6 & v_3 & v_4 & v_5 & v_1 & v_2 \\
v_6 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   \\
v_3 & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 1   \\
v_4 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   \\
v_5 & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   \\
v_1 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   \\
v_2 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0
}
\]
\end{document}


